# Are there pre-built virtual machines available for download that serve as a Tile Server for OpenStreetMaps?

Tags: openstreetmap, virtual-machine

The steps outlined [here](https://switch2osm.org/serving-tiles/manually-building-a-tile-server-20-04-lts/) go over how to install an [OpenStreetMaps](https://www.openstreetmap.org/) Tile Server on [Ubuntu](https://ubuntu.com/). The steps are quite long and will be copy / paste over and over again.

Is there any chance somebody has followed these steps on VirtualBox and generated an OVA file somewhere that I can download? That would save me (and many other people) a ton of time.